# Avoid casting operator arguments in C++

Tags: c++, casting, operator-keyword

Assume one has a templated class with overloading arithmetic operators doing very basic operations (e.g., on the integers), such that I can do

```
T a,b,c;
// ...
c=a+b;
```

Is there a way one can have the instruction

```
T d=2*a;
```

have the same meaning as

```
T d=(T)2*a;
```

without explicit casting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: Create an implicit constructor taking one `int` argument for `T`, and provide an overloaded `operator*` for `T`, and a free operator taking two `T`s:

```
struct T
{
    T(int);

    T operator*(T const &) const;

    friend T operator(T const & a, T const & b) { return a.operator*(b); }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Writing `a*2` works, but the compiler still does not like `2*a` without the cast. I already had the `operator*` for `T`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest `friend T operator*(T const &lhs, T const &rhs);`, this will work better. If your `T`s are lightweight, then you may even take them by value.

Comment: @Jarhmander: Yes, thank you. The implicit conversion only kicks in after the overload has been chosen, which requires the free two-argument overload. I added that.

Comment: @wwjoze: Sorry about that, Jarhmander said what the problem was: You need a free, two-argument overload of the operator as well, I added that.